# Как войти на сайт Спрашивай и посмотреть вопросы?

Tags: python, requests

Мне необходимо с помощью **Python "requests"** войти на сайт *http://sprashivai.ru/* и просмотреть вопросы, но все попытки увенчались тем, что я просто не вхожу в аккаунт и остаюсь на стартовой странице.
Моя задача по мимо получения вопросов ещё отвечать на них, но это уже на второй план.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать следующий код

```
import requests
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create session
session = requests.Session()

# create hash data
hash_data = hashlib.md5("your_password".encode('utf-8'))

# auth
session.post('http://sprashivai.ru/ajax/signin', data={
    'email': 'your_email', 'pass': hash_data.hexdigest()
})

# get questions page
questions_page = session.get('http://sprashivai.ru/questions/new').content

# parse questions
questions = []
questions_html = BeautifulSoup(
    questions_page, parser="html.parser", features="lxml"
)
questions_block = questions_html.find('div', {'id': 'inbox_questions'})
for item in questions_block.find_all('div', {'class': 'item'}):
    questions.append(item.find('div', {'class': 'inbox_question'}).text)

# show questions
for question in questions:
    print(question)
```

```
Часто врешь?
Кем ты хочешь стать?
Какой комедийный сериал вам нравится больше всего?
Какой любимый алкогольный напиток или коктейль?
Что для тебя главное в людях?
Пьешь энергетические напитки?
Любимая книжка в детстве?
Ты посещаешь театр, выставки?
Спортивная обувь или классика?
Если бы тебе пришлось слушать только одну песню, какая она была бы?
```